# Filter Postgres percent_rank before calculation but show all results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to run a percent_rank on a table, but filter which records the percent_rank is run on, but still include those rows that were filtered out, but give them a 0 percent_rank

For example, I have a users table and everyone has a point value assigned to them. I only want to percent_rank on people with >= 20 points, but not exclude them from the results. Meaning if they have 19 points I can still see their record, but their rank is 0

For example:

```
SELECT name,points,PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points) 
FROM users 
WHERE points >= 20;
```

But keep the people with less than 20 points in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a union here:

```sql
SELECT name, points, 0 AS pct_rank FROM users WHERE points < 20
UNION ALL
SELECT name, points, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points) FROM users WHERE points >= 20;
```

Comment: That's almost perfect, but how do I order the people with less than 20 points by points? putting an 'ORDER BY points' at the end of the first query gives a syntax error

Comment: @MarkReddington Adding `ORDER BY points` to the end of the full query should give you the ordering you want, since those with fewer than 20 points would by definition belong to the top half of the union anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `case`:

```
SELECT u.name, u.points,
       (CASE WHEN u.points >= 20
             THEN PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u.points >= 20 ORDER BY u.points) 
             ELSE 0
        END) as rank
FROM users u;
```

If you don't want to repeat the condition, you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT u.name, u.points,
       (CASE WHEN v.cond
             THEN PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY v.cond ORDER BY points) 
             ELSE 0
        END) as rank
FROM users u CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (u.points >= 20)) v(cond);
```